# Reset password token does not work multiple sites

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity-2

I needed to extend the generated reset password token timeout, so I switched from using `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider` to `DataProtectorTokenProvider`, using the data protection provider from `IAppBuilder.GetDataProtectionProvider()`.

```
UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(dataProtectionProvider.Create())
{
    TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(2)
};
```

But, when doing so I could no longer create the token on one site and use it to create a new password on another. The application uses multiple sites which are hosted on different servers.

```
var result = userManager.ResetPassword(user.Id, model.ResetPasswordToken, model.Password);
if (!result.Succeeded)
{
    // fails when the token is generated on a different site
}
```

I have tried using the same machine key, but that did not work.

Everything works fine when using `TotpSecurityStampBasedTokenProvider`, but it does not provide a way to extend the timeout.

Comment: do you reached to any solution?

Comment: @NMathur No, I ended up using a custom solution.